# Terraform ec2 instance don't creating

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-aws

Hello i have tf file for create my ec2 instance

```
resource "aws_vpc" "magazin-vpc" {
  cidr_block = 10.249.0.0/16
}

resource "aws_subnet" "magazin-subnet" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.magazin-vpc.id
  cidr_block        = "10.249.2.0/28"
}

resource "aws_instance" "magazin-vm" {
  ami           = "ami-058c02d7640104f1e"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  private_ip             = "10.249.2.5"
  subnet_id              = aws_subnet.magazin-subnet.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.magazin-sg.id]


  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = "unlimited"
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "magazin-ebs" {
  availability_zone = "eu-north-1a"
  size              = 10

  tags = {
    Name = "magazin-ebs"
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "magazin-ebs-att" {
  device_name = "/dev/sdh"
  volume_id   = aws_ebs_volume.magazin-ebs.id
  instance_id = aws_instance.magazin-vm.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "magazin-sg" {
  name        = "magazin-sg"

  ingress {
    description = "Allow port SSH from office"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["172.16.0.0/24"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow port HTTPS"
    from_port   = 9200
    to_port     = 9200
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["172.16.0.0/24"]
  }


  ingress {
    description = "Allow port HTTPS"
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["172.16.0.0/24"]
  }



  egress {
    description = "Allow ALL ports"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

and when i launch terraform apply i got

```
│ Error: Error launching source instance: InvalidParameter: Security group sg-090289f530fb61f8d and subnet subnet-08d14b2d736d10286 belong to different networks.
│       status code: 400, request id: 953d0bb8-cf92-4d8c-9923-d911cec3b453
│
│   with aws_instance.magazin-vm,
│   on dev-aerospike.tf line 6, in resource "aws_instance" "magazin-vm":
│    6: resource "aws_instance" "magazin-vm" {
│
```

why this error happens? because i declarate vpc and subnet in my terraform file
i'm using terraform 1.1.6
p.s the site says that the text should be longer but I don't know what else to write so I'll write that terraform is a cool thing, though I still don't know how to use it

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `vpc_id` in your `aws_security_group`. Without that your group will be created in a default VPC, not the one you are creating:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "magazin-sg" {
  name        = "magazin-sg"

  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.magazin-vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allow port SSH from office"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["172.16.0.0/24"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow port HTTPS"
    from_port   = 9200
    to_port     = 9200
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["172.16.0.0/24"]
  }


  ingress {
    description = "Allow port HTTPS"
    from_port   = -1
    to_port     = -1
    protocol    = "icmp"
    cidr_blocks = ["172.16.0.0/24"]
  }



  egress {
    description = "Allow ALL ports"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Comment: go this ╷
│ Error: Error launching source instance: Unsupported: The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
│       status code: 400, request id: 02bc10d5-045f-47a8-83cd-476b37850900
│
│   with aws_instance.magazin-vm,
│   on dev-aerospike.tf line 6, in resource "aws_instance" "magazin-vm":
│    6: resource "aws_instance" "magazin-vm" {
│

Comment: @krutoiadmin  This is a new error, related to the instance, not its security group. Thus new question should be asked.

Comment: @krutoiadmin can you provide the full output? Probably it has something to do with your attributes for private_ip and subnet_id. I thought, only one of those parameters are possible at the same time.